# wget - selective recursive download + page-rerequisites?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to scrape a forum site, to build a read-only archive.

I understand how to use -A and -R to limit the pages I retrieve, but is there a way to also retrieve page-prerequisites (e.g., icons and such)

Thanks!

Comment: --page-requisites ?

Comment: doesn't seem to do it - they get filtered out